# Carry bit in msp430

Tags: msp430, carryflag

I am writing simulator to microcontroller msp430. I cant understand when i should set carry bit. For example in `add` instruction:
`1+0x7FFF` setting carry bit or `1+0xFFFF`?

Comment: 17th bit not 16th   0x7FFF+1 means the N bit is set but not the carry.  0xFFFF+1 sets the carry bit as does 0x8000 + 0x8000.  the carry bit is the carry out of the msbit.   the real question is what do you do on a subtract, you invert the second operand and carry in a 1, but do you invert the carry out?  some architectures you do some you dont.  easiest just to get a $10 msp430 and try it.  V flag is typically set if msbit carry in and carry out differ. and n is just bit 15.

Comment: oh right (looking at my simulator) if it is a byte operation then 0xFF+1, bit 9 out of the alu basically is the carry bit, bit 7 is the n bit, etc.  if it is a word operation then it is like the above 0xFFFF+1 is 0x0000 with the carry bit set same as 0x8000+0x8000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `ADD` instruction, the carry bit is set on unsigned overflow.

You can deduce that from the examples in [TI documents](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau049f/slau049f.pdf). In particular, the second example in the documentation of `ADD` instruction ([page 3-22](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau049f/slau049f.pdf)) says that carry occurs on `ADD.B` if the result is greater than `0xff` (and for `ADD` and `ADDA` the limits are `0xffff` and `0xfffff` respectively - 8, 16 and 20 bits):

```
ADD.B           #10,R5     ; Add 10 to Lowbyte of R5
JC TONI                    ; Carry occurred, if (R5)  ≥  246 [0Ah+0F6h]
......                     ; No carry
```

The fact that there is a NEGATIVE bit in the msp430 status register in addition to the carry bit confirms this.

There are at least a couple of existing open-source MSP430 emulators, namely `mspsim` and Avrora. I suggest to use them as reference implementations.

Comment: That makes sense. I thougth that if we have negative bit then range for signed for 16 bit number is -32768 to 32767, and when we cross this range then we set carry bit, but this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There a two different instructions that implement `<`, JL (jump if less) and JLO (jump if lower).

The documentation of JL says that it

> allows comparison of signed integers.

The documentation of JLO says that it

> is used for the comparison of unsigned numbers.

JLO is the same as JNC, therefore, C is unsigned carry.